# I need to use a Java 8 Optional method that either gets the wrapped value, or calls a void return Consumer lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I am new to using optionals in Java 8. I know the method orElseGet() takes a supplier and orElseThrow() also takes a supplier that throws an exception. orElseThrow() might be a good one to use if I can construct my own exception and do something when that exception is triggered.

My main goal is to use a method that will either get the unwrapped value, or if the optional wraps null, then to actually execute an entirely different function.

Looking for the closest thing to:

```
class DoInsteadClass {
     public void doInstead() {
          // Do this instead
     }
}


Optional<String> myString = "Hello";
num.orElse(DoInsteadClass::doInstead);
```

If the only way to do this is orElseThrow(), and as long as I can handle the exception with the 'do this instead' code, that should be fine too. It just makes my codebase larger because I have to create a few different custom utility suppliers for the 2 or 3 cases where some of my  optional values would return null.

The problem is, .ifPresent() invokes the specified consumer with the value, otherwise does nothing. I need it to DO SOMETHING if the value is null. My current code utilizes a custom workaround where I first check if the value is null, and if it is, execute a chosen function. Then the next statement is the one that checks for ifPresent(). So this is doing the same thing, I am just looking for a more sugar-coated, one statement version.

Comment: Why aren't you just using an entirely normal `if (num.isPresent())` condition?

Comment: I think you mean `num.orElseGet` in the snippet?

Comment: And assigning `5` to an `Optional` also won't work - please check your code before posting here :)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Because I find that the .isPresent() method is pretty similar in lines of code to if (x != null), which is fine in most cases, but in my case, I have nested optional logic, and I don't want to create a pyramid of death.

Comment: @C-Otto Certainly the .orElseGet function could be a solution, but with the orElseGet function, you are forced to pass through a supplier. I am looking for a method JUST like .orElseGet except you can pass through a consumer instead of a supplier. That way, I can just simply pass through a lambda of what I want to happen, and it'll be a void, terminal operation. With a supplier, I have to implement all this extra logic of passing through a function that will return a supplier that  throws an exception.

Comment: The issue with the `Optional` approach is: what should the method return, so what should `X x = optional.foo(...)` assign to x, assuming `foo` does the magic you're looking for?

Comment: @C-Otto foo should not return anything. I'm looking for a built-in method that either returns the wrapped value if it exists (i.e. ifPresent()), OR, if it is null, then executes a void function of my choosing (i.e. System.out.println("value is null")

Comment: That won't work. If you have `X x = optional.foo(...)` there must be a defined value for `x`. The only way around that is to throw an exception.

Comment: @TylerDurden - What is the return type of the built-in method? Is it the parameterized type or void? It can't be both. If the former, what does the method return when the value is not present? If the latter, the value cannot be returned when present. You cannot accomplish both behaviors with an expression, but you can with an `if-else` statement. If the number is present, use the value, else do something else.

Comment: @AndyThomas There is no desired return type. I think this question is becoming overly complicated. My fault, let me simplify. I am simply wondering if Optional has a method that allows you to do the following: Optional.ifPresent() invokes the specified consumer with the value, otherwise does nothing. Is there an Optional method that invokes the specified consumer with the value if it is not null, otherwise calls ANOTHER function (instead of doing nothing)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JDK 9 there will be an `ifPresentOrElse` [method](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-) that will allow it.
For the time being, however, you may opt for the if statement, with `if(num.isPresent())`, or write your own reusable `ifPresentOrElse` method.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you for catching exactly what I was asking and knowing that it is coming in Java 9. For now, I have implemented it with a quick null check above the .ifPresent() method. This way, if the value is null, my chosen statements will run in the if-statement block, and if not, will execute the .ifPresent() method. Accepting this answer.