# Can Java Optional be used for flow control?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, nullable

I couldn't find a way to do the following with Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
if (SOME_OBJECT != null) {
  doSomething(SOME_OBJECT);
} else {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

By using `Optional`, I don't mean mean replacing `SOME_OBJECT == null` with `Optional.ofNullable(SOME_OBJECT).isPresent()`, which a much longer syntax than simply checking if null.

What I would expect is something like:

```
Optional.ofNullable(SOME_OBJECT)
  .ifPresent(this::doSomething)
  .orElse(this::doSomethingElse);
```

I couldn't find an API like the one I just wrote. Does it exist? If so, what is it? If not, why not? :)

The second piece of code looks like an anti-pattern :( Why? Perhaps Java's architects prevented this syntax on purpose...

Comment: It does seem surprising `ifPresent` doesn't return the `Optional`, and that there doesn't seem to be an `ifAbsent`.

Comment: I think the second piece of code might be an anti-pattern because it does three method calls, and seems to do more checks as well (`ifPresent` and `orElse` must re-check the result of `ofNullable`.  It seems at least as complicated as an if-then to read and would be somewhat harder to maintain.  All downside (even if small), no upside.

Comment: @markspace: I tend to feel that way about `Optional` as a whole. :-) But I haven't used it in anger (I haven't done any serious Java in years now), so my opinion there is reactionary and uninformed... :-)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417060/i-need-to-use-a-java-8-optional-method-that-either-gets-the-wrapped-value-or-ca/43417443#43417443) should help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think `Optional` was introduced as part of the streaming implementation.  It's used under the hood in streams to prevent `NullPointerException`s.  From that point of view I think it makes sense -- as part of a larger cohesive framework.  Randomly sprinkling your code with `Optional` probably isn't going to have a cohesive effect on its design or implementation, you'd need some good reason to use these sorts of objects.

Comment: @markspace: Yeah, I think that's it exactly.

Comment: If you already have a variable which contains null just keep your if and be happy. There is nothing to be gained to wrap it into an Optional for a single condition.

Comment: @eckes I think it was there for the purpose of presenting a short yet understandable example

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in this [Blog Article](http://blog.codefx.org/java/dev/java-9-optional/), Optionals will get a new method in Java 9: [`void ifPresentOrElse(Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-). So, with Java, 8 you don't have something like that at the moment.

Comment: I think it's easier to read `x == null` than `ifPresentOrElse`. Perhaps when combined with streams, the added value is more obvious?

Comment: Another source (from Java 9 official documentation):https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-

Answer (score 4):

As BdoubleB97 (Bdubzz) stated, Java 9 will implement `Optional#ifPresentOrElse` which will take a `Consumer<T>` which will be applied if the `Optional<T>` is present, and a `Runnable` which will be executed if the `Optional<T>` is empty.

You can either update now to the Java 9 Early Access build, or you can build the method yourself with the following:

```
public <T> void ifPresentOrElse(Optional<T> optional, Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction) {
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        action.accept(optional.get());
    } else {
        emptyAction.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As said Java 8 does not have a construct to do exactly what you want.

I know, it's ugly, far less readable than a simple if/then/else but you can do this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(someObject)
        .map(obj -> {
            System.out.println("present");
            return obj;
          })
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            System.out.println("not present");
            return null;
          });
```

The only side effect is that you have always return something.
Or on the other hand you can handle cleanly the case `isPresent()`.

```
Optional.ofNullable(someObject).ifPresent(obj -> {
  System.out.println("present");
});
```

Comment: While possible, I can't think of a situation where this would be a good idea. It is way more complicated than the `if-else`, and the unused return values  further obfuscate the intent. (In addition to abusing `map()` and `orElseGet()` for side effects).

Comment: Right... I was just trying to understand if we can avoid this limitation only with Java 8. But the result is a little bit too ugly :)